# How can i know specific value on a form using `request.form`?

Tags: asp.net

How can i know specific value on a form using `request.form`?
I am trying it long but no success.

```
i want to check something like this
if (request.form.contains("text_check"))  //But it doesn't work
{
go in;

}
else{

here we go;
}
```

i want to know specific value from AllKeys, and total count of all keys too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if a certain key exists in the `Request.Form` collection you can do so like this:

```
if(Request.Form.AllKeys.Any(k => k == "text_check")) { ... }
```

and to then get it's value:

```
if(Request.Form.AllKeys.Any(k => k == "text_check")) 
{ 
     var textCheckValue = Request.Form["text_check"];
}
```

To get the total number of keys then:

```
var count = Request.Form.AllKeys.Count();
```

Answer (score 3):

To check if a key exists in the form data, you can simply compare the value to null:

```
if (Request.Form["text_check"] != null) {
```

If the key exists, you always get a string value back, even if the value is empty.

If you want to check if there is a non-empty value, you can use the `String.IsNullOrEmpty` method:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["text_check"])) {
```

Comment: Seems the best and easiest way.  I tried passing javascript null and it shows up on the server as empty but not null.  That works for me. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you are using server side controls, you can use `Request.Form.Contains(text_check.UniqueId)` to make sure form is having that value during postback.